# Vertical center text inside span tag

Tags: html, css, text, center, vertical-alignment

My problem is I cannot centralize the text inside span tag. My CSS as below:

```
span {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

or

```
span {
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

There is gap between bottom of text and bottom of span tag.

Please see the image

[image]

Comment: note the in your image you have ONLY uppercase letter. Consider `jqp` letters and see the difference

Answer (score -2):

Use line-height property in order to achieve aligning to middle. Set its value to be same value of the height property. In addition, set margin and padding to 0 so there won't be default margins who could cause gap

```
.middleText {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #85D389;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```